# How to count data in Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

How to count data in Java and MySQL? The final result is shown to me through JOptionpane but I got an error message with this code.

```
 try { DBConn.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBConn.Url, DBConn.User, DBConn.PWD);
          java.sql.Statement count = DBConn.conn.createStatement();
          String SQLCount = "select count(*) from datastudent where parklevel = 'Level 1' ";
                ResultSet rs = count.executeQuery(SQLCount);
                  while (rs.next()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"number of existing parking is " + rs);
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            //
            }
       }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Answer (score 1):

You should print `rs.getInt (1)`. When you select a count of some data from some table, the result is returned as an integer column in the result set.

So try :

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"number of existing parking is " + rs.getInt (1));`

Answer (score 0):

try this. your query return only one value, so no need loop.

```
           ResultSet rs = count.executeQuery(SQLCount);
           rs.next();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"number of existing parking is " + rs.getInt(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading any values from `ResultSet`, see [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Needs `rs.getInt(1)`